# place photo to panorama via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

I'm facing a difficult situation, I need to place/insert photo to synthetic panorama, I mean to place it on top of the panorama and make it moveable, but only in the area of panorama.

I can load and show panorama like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            data: { compare : send_image_name },
            url: 'get_panorama.php',
            method: 'POST', // or GET
            success: function( path_to_panorama_response )
            {
                var path_to_panorama = JSON.parse( path_to_panorama_response );

                var square1 = document.createElement('div');
                var image = document.createElement('img');

                square1.id = 'square1';
                image.id = 'uploaded_image';

                image.src = path_to_panorama[0];

                square1.appendChild( image );
                document.body.appendChild( square1 );
            }
        });
```

Don't you have any ideas, please?